# Accessing Javascript globals from aspx page to another

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, global-variables, aspnet-compiler

Here's the underlying folder structure:

```
|   ...
|   Top.aspx
|   ...
|
\---Include
        ...
        ClientScriptGlobals.aspx
        ...
\---Config
        ...
        Project.config
        ...
```

Here's a snippet of `Top.aspx`:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Codebehind="Top.aspx.vb" Inherits="Project.Top"%>

<!--DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"-->

<html>  
    <head><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10" />    
        <title>....</title> 
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="imagetoolbar" CONTENT="no">

        <!--#include virtual="..."-->
        <!--#include virtual="Include/ClientScriptGlobals.aspx" -->
        <!--#include virtual="...." -->
        ....
    </head>
</html>
```

And finally `ClientScriptsGlobal.aspx`:

```
<script language="javascript">      
    //Globals                   
    ...
    var FullTextSearchStatus = "<%= FullTextSearchStatus %>"
    ...
</script>
```

---

To give some context, `Top.aspx` includes `ClientScriptGlobals.aspx` so that I can access its global variables, which are also being used throughout the application.

My issue arises when I use `aspnet_compiler.exe` to pre-compile my application. Once it reaches `ClientScriptsGlobal.aspx`, it returns a bunch of errors like this:

> error BC30451: Name 'FullTextSearchStatus" is not declared.

**So now my question is, how can I tell `ClientScriptsGlobal.aspx` the location of `FullTextSearchStatus`'s definition?**

Keep in mind that when I opt to not pre-compile the application, these errors do not occur because the Javascript is not being compiled beforehand and therefore, its references have already been established (if that's the correct way describe this).

Comment: What is `FullTextSearchStatus`?

Comment: @HanletEscaño An XML element defined in a `.config` file. I'll update the directory tree at the top of my post to show its location.